# Unable to Authenticate Firebase with GitHub Personal Access Token (Previously Worked)

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

This code use to work, but now I'm getting errors when trying to authenticate. Here's a simple example so you can recreate the issue. It's a Node script using the latest version of the firebase module (3.4.1).

I just generated a new GitHub personal access token with all permissions enabled. I'm still getting the same error.

```
var firebase = require('firebase');
var config = {
  apiKey: "REDACTED",
  authDomain: "REDACTED",
  databaseURL: "REDACTED",
  storageBucket: "REDACTED",
  messagingSenderId: "REDACTED"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

var credential = firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider.credential('REDACTED');
firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)
```

Here's the error:

```
{  
   "error":{  
      "errors":[  
         {  
            "domain":"global",
            "reason":"invalid",
            "message":"Unsuccessful check authorization response from Github: {\"message\":\"Bad credentials\",\"documentation_url\":\"https://developer.github.com/v3\"}"
         }
      ],
      "code":400,
      "message":"Unsuccessful check authorization response from Github: {\"message\":\"Bad credentials\",\"documentation_url\":\"https://developer.github.com/v3\"}"
   }
}
```

Any ideas? I've looked though recent changelogs and I wasn't able to find anything related to this.

**Update**

It looks like support for Personal Access Tokens was removed. I've switched the test app over to anonymous authentication which works well for my purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely the GitHub account you used to generate the OAuth access token does not match the GitHub client id you configured in your Firebase console project settings. Login to the Firebase console and update your GitHub client id and secret to that of the GitHub client you used to generate the access token.

Comment: Thanks for reading and responding. Unfortunitely, the client id and client secret are correct. I've added the values from GitHub to the Firebase console. Any other ideas?

Comment: Try to sign in to GitHub using signInWithPopup. Get the access token returned in the result.credential field. Try to signInWithCredential using that and it should work. Whatever service you used to get your GitHub credential must not match the one you set up in the console.

Comment: I can confirm that works, but that requires a UI. The great thing about the above code was that it could be used in test cases (up until recently). The credential I pass into "firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider.credential" is indeed a GitHub provided credential. 

I dug into the error object and found the following error code: auth/internal-error

Comment: I was trying to demonstrate that a GitHub access token generated using the same project settings saved in the Firebase console would work. The access token returned in signInWithPopup will work as it belongs to the same GitHub project. The one you were using must have been generated using a different client id.  You don't have to use signInWithPopup. You can use signInWithCredential. Just ensure it is from the same GitHub project as the one you have configured in the Firebase console.

Comment: When you go to https://github.com/settings/developers, the same OAuth application should be used in the Firebase console and in the code where you generate the access token.

Comment: I only have the one app on GitHub and Firebase. The token I'm using is a personal access token which is not generated with a client id. There is a separate section in GitHub where these are created (https://github.com/settings/tokens).

Comment: I'm not sure why they're throwing an error (used to work). Is there a better way to debug what's going on here? I'd usually dive into the source but it doesn't seem to be open source.

Comment: This is enforced on the backend. It is not a client issue. Personal access tokens are not supposed to work as they are not associated with a specific oauth app. You have to generate the access token from the created github oauth application.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was able to switch some tests over to anonymous authentication which has worked well for my purposes.